# Create cookie in safari after successful login in app

Tags: ios, iphone, cookies, safari

I have an app that uses `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` to perform login using the following code :

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            loginNameField.text, @"username",
                            loginPasswordField.text, @"password",
                            uniqueUserToken, @"device_id",
                            nil];

    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [self.operationManager.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:LOGIN_URL parameters:params error:nil];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation* operation = [self.operationManager HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    //completion block

    }

[self.operationManager.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

What I want to do is, once the user logs-in with the app, create a cookie in Safari, so the user is redirected directly to the main site instead of login page, in the browser.

I tried using the following, but Safari still lands on the login page of the website:

```
            NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@&device_id=%@", loginNameField.text, loginPasswordField.text, uniqueUserToken];

            NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length ]];

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:LOGIN_URL]];

            [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST" ];

            [request setHTTPBody:myRequestData];

            NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

            [connection release];

            [request release];
```

Now I understand sandboxing of apps in iOS, hence the question here. I have read other questions, but my knowledge of `javaScript` is in it's infancy. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use either [NSHTTPCookie](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookie_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or save the username and password in KeychainStore with a library like [UICKeyChainStore](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore).  Then in AppDelegate you can check if the user is logged or not. I personally use the second option because it saves securely the data until the user choses to log out. but a more temporary solution is to just save the data  NSHTTPCookie

```
    NSArray *cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookiesForURL: theURL];
for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies) 
{
    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] delete or set here];
}
```